# How to use scope for relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have defined my `Category` model this way:

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'par_cat');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'par_cat', 'id');
    }
    public function scopeVisible($q)
    {
        return $q->whereActive(1)->whereAccepted(1);
    }

    public function scopeDefOrder($q) {
       return $q->orderBy('priority', 'ASC')->orderBy('name','ASC');
   }

}
```

Now when I want to get visible categories with predefined orderby using scope I can do something like this:

```
$categories = Category::visible()->defOrder()->get();
```

But what in case if I want to get also visible children?

I could use syntax like this:

```
$categories = Category::with(['children' =>function($q) {
         $q->visible()->defOrder();
     }])->visible()->defOrder()->get();
```

but it seems to be a bit too complicated to use only scope for children. Is there any other way? I could imagine using for example:

```
$categories = Category::with('children#visible#defOrder')
          ->visible()->defOrder()->get();
```

but probably there is no such construction.

The only solution I found is creating one more extra relationship:

```
public function visibleDefOrderChildren()
{
    return $this->children()->visible()->defOrder();
}
```

and now I can also use:

```
$categories = Category::with('visibleDefOrderChildren')->visible()->defOrder()->get();
```

but in case I had more scopes and not use always `visible` scope with `defOrder` scope, it wouldn't make sense creating dozens methods just to use scopes for relationship.

Is there any other simpler solution? Or I have choose between closure and creating extra methods to append scopes to relationship?

Comment: It's more of design question. You must be just playing with Eloquent, otherwise you just create the methods you need to match your scenarios/tests. Try something 'real' with TDD and you will most likely notice that **1** `scopeDefOrder` is not meaningful, **2** you create only methods that need to be there. And Eloquent will be just an implementation of one of your interfaces so it won't matter how you do it - be it closure, scopes or whatever.